# Apache2 não executa o php

Tags: php, html, apache

Olá, boa noite!

Tenho instalado no meu PC o Apache2 e o php7.2. Só que quando tento executar um arquivo.**php** no navegador **Firefox** ele me retorna o mesmo arquivo para eu fazer o download. Já pesquisei no Google a solução para esse problema mas nenhuma das apresentados resolveram.

O código é simples:

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo "Olá mundo!"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Então,desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Você colocou o arquivo na pasta que distribui ele para web? está acessando pela url fornecida pelo apache?

Comment: A url que utilizo é esta : localhost/meu_programa/arquivo.php.

Comment: qual sistema operacional?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa remover um comentário neste arquivo `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Ja tive esse problema e isso resolveu.

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

se não funcionar tente adicionar isso ao seu .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Outra opção é tentar instalar o mod php

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Se alguma das opções acima funcionar comenta abaixo, pode ajudar outras pessoas!

Comment: Pois é, não encontro esse httpd.conf, é o mesmo que apache2.conf?

Comment: isso mesmo, no ubuntu é esse arquivo.

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo. Ele diz que não tenho permissões para alterar o arquivo

Comment: Não consigo encontrar este comentário no arquivo : LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

Comment: Roda este comando então, `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php` você não instalou o php ainda

Comment: Já foi instalado o php.Porém, ainda continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Roda o comando acima para instalar a extensão dele no apache e depois reinicia o apache `sudo service apache2 restart` faça o teste e veja se o resultado é o mesmo

Comment: Sem sucesso.Vou desinstalar e instalar novamente.

Comment: faça isso, use essa instalação.
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql`

Comment: Fiz isso, mas ainda continua na mesma.

Comment: `sudo a2enmod php7
sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo. Ainda ele continua exibindo um caixa de dialogo para eu fazer o downloado arquivo.php

Comment: @ÍcaroTimóteo essa caixa de dialogo consegue atualizar a pergunta e colocar um print disso.

Comment: É aquela quando você vai fazer o download de qualquer coisa, seja arquivo,música, video etc.